# Merging overlays and camera pictures to create high quality images in Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-image

I'm trying to emulate something that is working in an app called [InstaWeather](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.byss.mobi.instaweatherfree&hl=en_GB). They have numerous overlays that you can switch through, that merge with the picture you take to produce a custom weather image that you can share.

It doesn't seem like these are canvas drawn on, and I can never get anywhere near as clear and high res drawing things on via canvas. Does anyone have any idea how the overlay and taken camera image are merged? Bearing in mind the overlays are based on the current weather data so aren't pre-existing.

I'm not sure if this will be regarded as too general, but I do have a specific issue in that the images I create often suffer hugely from being drawn on via canvas.

Comment: You should put in more detail as to how you are drawing/compositing your image. Examples of clear vs not clear would help.

Comment: I actually have sort of tried doing so before. I may try again, where I would include code samples. I was hoping to tackle it from a different angle and ask something like this, hoping to find someone who had a good idea of how an app that achieves what I'm trying to do does so. I think this would help me most, and I'll gladly add an update with more info that may help someone else if I can get somewhere with it.

Comment: Have you looked at the Android Open Source Project Gallery2 app which has filters and such? While not quite what you are looking for, it should give you ideas. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/